# Internal Methods [[GetOwnProperty]]

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I faced an question when I was reading ECMAScript® 2021 Language Specification.
In this document in section "6.1.7.2 Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots" in "Table 6", mentioned that there is a internal method called [[GetOwnProperty]].
The confusion is understandable for me that there are methods like:

> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor() | Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors() | Object.getOwnPropertyNames()

and another one but there is no a method with this name.

What is the actual meaning and the point of [[GetOwnProperty]] internal method?
Why did they mention GetOwnProperty as method name while in practical there is a method with "getOwnPropertyDescriptor" name?
Can you please give some details for better understanding of the term?

Comment: It's a convention used by the spec for organizational purposes. The "internal methods" are procedures that are referenced in many places in the long and complicated language spec.

Comment: Just FYI, usually when you see a method/ property name like `[[ name ]]`, it usually refers to native functions/ property. Functions like `.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` exposed functions that consumes native functions internally. But this is my assumption and maybe someone can correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If you take a look at the [specification for `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-object.getownpropertydescriptor), you'll see the difference

Comment: @Bergi thanks bro, It is far away from where I am reading right now, but it completely untied the knot, thanks